# Securely passing parameters in JSP/Servlet (No Frameworks)

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets, web

We have a JSP page and a Servlet page, where we pass the parameters via URL from JSP to Servlet. Below is the JSP link

```
<a href="OpenServlet?idClient=23">Allergies</a>
```

In our servlet, we do some process like below.

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idClient"));
//Do the work

RequestDispatcher d = request.getRequestDispatcher("view.jsp");
d.forward(request,response);
```

Unfortunately this makes the `idClient` 100% visible and it is also editable. We have noticed that the user can simply edit the `idClient` from the URL and access other client information too! Not only that, any one can access anyones info, whether the client is belong to them or not!

How can we stop this?

Comment: How do you normally get which user is logged in?

Comment: @immibis: Using sessions.

Comment: 1. Get the logged in user. 2. Check whether they're supposed to have access to this client's details. 3. If not, show an error page instead of the client details page.

Comment: @immibis:Using another SQL Query? I mean, to load the data we have a SQL query, so we need another one, is that what you meant please?

Comment: Exactly what the @immibis said. Just ensure that logged in user has access to given resource.

Comment: @JustCause another query or embed it into the one you got. It depends now how your DB is designed like. Something like SELECT * FROM allergy WHERE id=1 AND owner=2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get the logged-in user.
2. Check whether that user is supposed to be able to access this client's details.
3. If not, return an error page instead of the client details page.

I can't be more specific without knowing the details of your existing code and database structure.